# How to solve SettingWithCopyWarning error when I add a new column with partial rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add a new column called running_std, but only on after row 365 onwards, the function running_std() will return one column of new data but 365 rows short, so my results are not full length.  So I need to specify to save the result from running_std in a new column called df[running_std] but only after the first 365 rows, how can I do this?  This is what I got:

```
df.iloc[364:]['running_std'] = running_std(df['close'], 365)
```

This is the error I get:

```
<ipython-input-28-00793e1ff030>:8: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
df.iloc[364:]['running_std'] = running_std(df['close'], 365)
```

What should I do to solve this error?

Comment: This is a warning, not an error. Is `df` derived from another dataframe?

Comment: @Erfan - I think not, it is from `df.iloc[364:]['running_std']`

Comment: Yes you are right @jezrael +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is if use `df.iloc[364:]['running_std']`, because it create new `Series` from 365 rows called `running_std` instead new column, more info in [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#evaluation-order-matters).

If default `RangeIndex` is possible use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df.loc[364:, 'running_std'] = running_std(df['close'], 365)
```

If another index like `DatetimeIndex` use indexing:

```
df.loc[df.index[364:], 'running_std'] = running_std(df['close'], 365)
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'close':[50,40,20,30,50]})

def running_std(x, a):
    return x


df.loc[2:, 'running_std'] = running_std(df['close'], 365)
print (df)
   close  running_std
0     50          NaN
1     40          NaN
2     20         20.0
3     30         30.0
4     50         50.0
```

Comment: Very much appreciate the detailed answer, can I add you on LinkedIn and ask you for some help with my project?  Would be much appreciated.

Comment: @BillSoftwareEngineer - Not so easy, because not use `LinkedIn` and now  a bit busy (some deadline)